# I am trying to make a bot that plays an mp3 file by a command but it doesn't work with no error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I made so it connects to the voice channel by the command .join and it supposed to play a sound that i saved. This is made for a voice channel with chill music so that they don't have to copy and paste a YouTube link. I am using python 3.9

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".") 

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):

    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
        guild = ctx.guild
        voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=guild)
        audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music.mp3')
    
        if not voice_client.is_playing():
            voice_client.play(audio_source, after=None)
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Where is it going to fetch `music.mp3` from?

Comment: same directory and folder. There is no error or anything it just doesn't play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

bot = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):

    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
        return
    
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    audio_source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music.mp3'))

    if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        ctx.voice_client.play(audio_source, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: It has a green ring around it when i use it in a voice channel but there is no sound. I thought it was because i made the volume minimum but no. I do't know what is the problem

Comment: That's probably because you don't have `youtube_dl` imported. I've edited my answer, so look at it again. Basically, you need to add `from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL` to the top of your file.

Comment: @AdityaTomar you don't need youtube-dl to play music tho

Comment: @GeeTransit Then the only other thing I can think about is that OP's song might be in a different folder. So it's not actually playing anything because it isn't able to get `music.mp3`.

Comment: i can try writing out a path for the file and that can help
Edit: yes it worked. thank you for all the help